# Nested Examples: in a Cucumber Feature File

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, calabash-android

Is something like the following possible? I am testing using calabash-android.

I have 3 types of users
I want to log each of the 3 in and make sure the screen has each of the 9 elements.

Can I nest the 3 user types and then have each user type look for each of the 9 elements?

```
Feature: Overview screen on Mobile App
  In order to access all the features of the Mobile App
  As a user of the Mobile App
  I want to be able to access the features through the Overview Screen

  @high
  Scenario Outline: Overview Screen Appearance
    Given I login to an <type> account

    Examples:
      | type          |
      | secure        |
      | user          |
      | admin         |

    Then I should see the <element>

    Examples:
      | element                     |
      | Overview Header             |
      | Status Icon                 |
      | Status Text                 |
      | Status Time                 |
      | Current Temp Icon           |
      | Navigation Overview Text    |
      | Navigation Overview Icon    |
      | Navigation Activity Text    |
      | Navigation Activity Icon    |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds more like a task for using a datatable. The code implementing the step would then check that each element of the datatable parameter is present on the page.

```
Scenario Outline: Overview Screen Appearance
  Given I login to an <type> account
  Then I should see the following elements:
    | element                     |
    | Overview Header             |
    | Status Icon                 |
    | Status Text                 |
    | Status Time                 |
    | Current Temp Icon           |
    | Navigation Overview Text    |
    | Navigation Overview Icon    |
    | Navigation Activity Text    |
    | Navigation Activity Icon    |
  Examples:
    | type          |
    | secure        |
    | user          |
    | admin         |
```

Comment: Excellent. Will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using FactoryGirl.

If you have complex data model, you can simply abstract it out in the form of factories instead of making complex **static** feature files.